# How to have 3D rotation of a trajectory line in a 2D Game rotate depending on input position

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, angle, euler-angles

I've had a codementor try and help me figure out how this game is doing this 3d rotation of their trajectory line but we couldn't get it to work yet in Unity.

```
Game that does the rotation I'm trying to replicate
https://guselect.itch.io/cheese-bit





Here's the code we attempted to emulate it with butit  ultimately doesn't work
```

```
   var worldClickPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            var facingDirection = (worldClickPosition - playerScript.transform.position).normalized;
            var angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.right, facingDirection);
            var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,angle - 90f, angle -90f);
            trajectories.Rotate(Input.mousePosition);
```

Comment: if "trajectories" is a Transform, you are setting mouse position as an input for Rotate method not the angle.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.